# Firebase Invite for web application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, firebase, firebase-invites

so far I have seen only iOS and Android. Could we use this Firebase feature of invite in a web application?

Thank you

Comment: Same question.  Is there any plan to add this capability?

Answer (score 1):

Right now firebase invites api supports only android, ios and c++ SDKs